# Chi-Suare Test: p-Value

Tags: statistics, python

I have a simple question about the Chi-Square test (unfortunately I only had the extreme maths basics when I was in university). I have the following results:

[image]

I think I will use the old data as expected frequency and the new data as observed frequency. My result is as follows.

```
               id  New       old     Chisquare
0      (-26, -22]  17858.0  31704.0  10735.340800
1      (-22, -18]  16060.0  18990.0    534.551681
2      (-18, -14]  20023.0  13964.0   1833.465565
3      (-14, -10]  19845.0   5573.0  10264.045553
4       (-10, -6]  12757.0    779.0  11246.569256
5        (-6, -2]   6446.0      0.0   6446.000000
6         (-2, 2]   1391.0      0.0   1391.000000

Total              94380.0  71010.0  42450.972855
```

how can i calculate the p value? i have 4 lines of freedom! I use the python code for this:

```
1 - stats.chi2.cdf((total(Chi^2)), 4)
```

But my result is:

```
>>> 1 - stats.chi2.cdf(42450.972855, 4)
0.0
```

So I wanted to ask if this can be correct, although a change in the data can be recognised in the figure.

Comment: Unfortunately (unless I missed it) I don't see anything in this about Earth Science as posted? There is a [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com), though there may be a chance they consider it a basic question answered elsewhere/by other questions, so you may need to research first. Frustrating when you're struggling to find the answer (I well know), but unfortunately how stack exchange is setup as of now.  Could also try or expanding your question to more directly relate to Earth Science choices, or try [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=earthscience.stackexchange.com).